# Avoiding exclusive schema lock error with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, schema-locks, error-000464

I have a script for updating some features on my database every night (just for copying and replacing some features). This features are "read-only".
My problem is that I can't avoid that these features are opened by users, and my script can show the following error:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000464: Cannot get exclusive schema lock. 
              Either being edited or in use by another application.
```

Can I force the phyton script, via some command, copying the files, even been opened by some user?
Can I take down all the connections on my database before running the script?

Comment: This appears to be an arcpy/arcgisscripting error. Please confirm which you are using, and also which database you are using.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that you are working with SDE.

You should kill all connections using `sdemon` command-line tool.

1. If there is an ArcSDE installed on PC where you a running the script then you can execute `sdemon -o kill` locally to kill all connections. Take a look at this [help topic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/Support_files/serveradmin/sdemon.htm#kill_ex). I am not sure is it killing direct-connections on 10.0. I remember that it was a kind of a problem on 9.3 and that it is definitely killing direct-connections on 10.1.
2. If you don't have ArcSDE installed and it is running only on a separate server then you can execute this command remotely from Python. There is some discussion in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173977/remote-server-command-execute).

Comment: Yes, I'm using SDE (installed on a server).
But the "sdemon -o kill" command returned a syntax error.

Comment: The sdemon command has to be executed in ArcSDE.
Can I put it on my Python script?

Comment: Take a look at [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module. Also there is nice questions here: [How to call external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python) and [Running shell command from python and capturing the output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output).

Comment: Command `sdemon -o kill` is not enough. You should pass additional parameters, take a look at provided [link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/Support_files/serveradmin/sdemon.htm#kill_ex).

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility since you said you are using SDE is to delete shared locks from the `layer_locks` and `table_locks` tables using SQL, PL/SQL, T-SQL, etc. e.g.:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_LOCKS WHERE SDE_ID = :b1 AND REGISTRATION_ID = :b2
```

I would definitely not recommend this approach on a versioned geodatabase. See also: [How are the various lock mechanisms implemented in ArcSDE and the geodatabase?](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/27034)

Answer (score 2):

If the preference is to remove specific SDE user locks, [there is a way to do this via arcpy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000061000000).  I prefer this approach because it doesn't require that you jump onto the database server to perform an sde command.  I can disconnect any unwanted locks, then perform data updates all in one script/process.

Example from the above link is very useful:

```
import arcpy

admin_workspace = "Database Connections/tenone@sde.sde"
arcpy.env.workspace = admin_workspace
user_name = "GDB"

# Look through the users in the connected user list and get the SDE ID.
# Use the SDE ID to disconnect the user that matches the username variable
users = arcpy.ListUsers() # The environment is set, no workspace is needed.
for item in users:
    if item.Name == user_name:
        arcpy.DisconnectUser(admin_workspace, item.ID)
```

Comment: I ran this, and seemed to work, until it hit my current sessionID, and threw an error.  Is there a way to loop through users and skip the current user (if item.Name == 'DBO' and item.ID != <current user's session ID>)?  I cannot find a way to find the current user's session ID.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with postgresql but I think this post can lead you to the right direction:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108876/kill-a-postgresql-session-connection