# Debugging ERROR 000464: Cannot get exclusive schema lock?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, schema-locks, error-000464

I am trying to run the "Near" tool in Arcmap. Both my layers involved are on a SDE database. When I run the tool I get the following error...

```
ERROR 000464: Cannot get exclusive schema lock.  Either being edited or in use by another application.
```

I do not:

- Have an edit session open.
- Have another application open.

I saw this [Link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28948/python-script-how-to-avoid-exclusive-schema-lock-error) but I do not have ArcSDE installed locally so cannot execute "sdemon -o kill" to locally kill all connections...

How can I get an exclusive schema lock and/or bypass this error?

**Windows 7, ArcGIS 10, Versioned SDE GeoDatabase**

---

After reading this:

"In the Windows File Explorer, I looked at the properties of the folder where my script was putting its data. I saw that the folder was set to READ ONLY." [Source](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1729&t=246504)

I trying running the cmd command to set turn off read-only still no luck.

```
attrib -r pathTofolder
```

After further reading found that the read-only attribute in windows 7 is normal, and has more to do with windows system files then ability to write to the file folder.

---

Today after reconciling, thinking that all locks on the database world have been removed from the previous day. Tried running the "Near" tool again, but still no luck still gives the schema lock error...

Comment: Is your 'Near' operation the first geoprocessing call you're making on the layers? Is it possible that they have already been opened/loaded in Arc?

Comment: Yes I 'Near' is the first geoprocessing call on these layers. I have the layers 'Open' as in they show up in the table of contents of ArcMap.

Comment: What happens if you close ArcMap and run the tool from ArcCatalog?

Comment: From ArcCatalog Same Error..

Comment: Do you have administrator rights on your 'pathTofolder?' Do you have the rights to even create schema locks on ArcSDE?

Comment: Yes I have administrator rights to the folder. The schema locks are created automatically by ESRI. " In most cases; ArcGIS automatically applies and releases shared locks and exclusive locks on datasets in the geodatabase to help you manage your changes without causing conflicts with other users."

Comment: For clarification - are your input layers in ArcSDE or a file geodatabase, you mention both?

Comment: I know you said you don't have SDE installed on your local box, but can you RDP into the DB server where SDE resides? You need to run sdemon -o kill and kill the other processes that are accessing the same database. Or in 10.1, you can kill the locks with a Direct Connection I think.

Comment: @ChadCooper Wow My bad, input layers are ArcSDE. I managed to get sdemon on my machine still trying to figure out how to use it however...

Comment: Maybe try Generate Near Table (Analysis) which gives you an output folder (set it to some other place locally, and then try elsewhere on the network), if that works, then its def. a problem with schema locks w/in the GDB you are working in. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001n000000

Comment: ...an output you can set to a different folder...

Comment: In ArcCatalog if you're running 10.1 you can right click on the SDE connection --> Administration --> Administer database and look at what or who is setting up the locks....maybe this will help narrow down the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the data to a local location (I personally use C:\Data), and attempt to run the tool on a local version of the data.  If this works, you can load the data back into SDE.  I've had too many problems with schema locks on SDE in both v9 and v10, and there are many ways to attempt to remove the locks.  The problem would really come to a head if you can successfully run the tool on a local version and then NOT load the data back into SDE, which would indicate a deeper problem.